# How to write a script/batch file on windows?

Tags: windows, shell, scripting, macros, cmd

I am using a machine where I do not have administrator privileges and I need to set the e.g. `JAVA_HOME` each time I boot.

Thus, I'd like to write a script that sets the desired `classpath` automatically.
How do I do this?

Comment: ... msdos script should have a 'bat' extension..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You surely *can* set the environment variables with a batch file each time you need them, but bear in mind that this will only work for the current process (i. e. the `cmd` instance you're invoking the batch from) and processes spawned from there. I think you'd rather want persistent environment variables.

Now, in the UNIX world you'd just put them into your shell startup script. In Windows ... not exactly that way.

1. Right click on "My Computer", select "Properties".
2. There, go to the "Advanced" tab
3. Click the button labeled "Environment variables"
4. You can set `JAVA_HOME` and `GRAILS_HOME` under "User variables" there.

You would only need administrator access for changing the system environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

You would want a file with .bat extension for Windows.

```
SET JAVA_HOME=path
SET GRAILS_HOME=path
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you could write a .BAT file (BATch), and then simply double-click it each time you log in. a .BAT file is simply a plain text file filled with any commands you would normally issue at the command prompt, e.g.:

cd c:\Temp
c:
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Program Files\Some Directory\Some Subdirectory

You can optionally precede each line with the @ symbol to stop it being echoed to the command window when it executes.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the following :

```
SETX JAVA_HOME path
SETX GRAILS_HOME path
```

If you're allowed they will be set in your profile and you won't need to run them again hopefully. Other wise you'll need to follow @Android's answer

Comment: `setx` doesn't exist on vanilla Windows XP, unfortunately.

Comment: whoops sorry keep forgetting that